# $ \hbar^2$ Correction to the Bohr-Sommerfeld Quantization Condition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, approximations, semiclassical, deformation-quantization

We can get the Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization from the WKB method as [answered](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64212/). Since we use approximation, there should be an error in the system, I know this is not right all the time; in some conditions approximation can yield the real result. So, is there a way to find the $ \hbar^2$ correction?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/648131/how-does-an-operator-degenerate-into-a-function/648588#648588), as well as [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31894/how-does-one-quantize-the-phase-space-semiclassically/31951#31951). Actually, there are striking failures of the approximation even at a level below  $\hbar^2$. The best link is through deformation quantization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, from the point of WKB, if we could find $S_2$, coefficient of the term $ (\hbar/i)^2$, and plug it into the Schrödinger equation, we would have find the correction. From the WKB, we already know that $S_0 = \int p(x)dx$ and $S_1 = - \frac{1}{2} \ln p + C$. We also have the condition, $ S_1''+(S_1')^2+2S_0'S_2' = 0$, so plugging $S_1$and $S_0$ written in terms of $p$, we got $S_2$ = $\frac{1 \cdot p'}{4 \cdot p^2} + \frac{1}{8} \int \frac{p'^2}{p^3}dx$. WKB says that, $\psi = e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}s}$ and $s = s_0 + \frac{\hbar}{i}s_1 + \frac{\hbar}{i}^2 s_2$. If we plug $s$ containing the $s_2$ term to the Schrödinger equation, we can find the correction.